# GTK Tree prevent selecting rows

Tags: c, gtk

I am doing a GTK C program on Windows and I want to prevent the user from being able to select/highlight any rows in the tree view. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "gtk_tree_selection_set_select_function ()" seems to be exactly what you want.

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTreeSelection.html#gtk-tree-selection-set-select-function